# The difference usages of scala.reflect.classTag

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala and I saw there are two usages for retrieving the classTags in the codebase. Can I say below two usages (stringClassTag v.s stringClassTag2) are equivalent? thank you.

```
import scala.reflect.{classTag, ClassTag}

val stringClassTag: ClassTag[String] = implicitly[ClassTag[String]]

val stringClassTag2: ClassTag[String] = classTag[String]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are identical.

If you look at the definition of [`classTag`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/bf45e199e96383b96a6955520d7d2524c78e6e12/src/library/scala/reflect/package.scala#L51):

```scala
def classTag[T](implicit ctag: ClassTag[T]) = ctag
```

And [`implicitly`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/bf45e199e96383b96a6955520d7d2524c78e6e12/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L218):

```scala
@inline def implicitly[T](implicit e: T): T = e
```

`implicitly` is a generic method to "summon" an implicit value of any type `T`, `classTag` does the same but only for `ClassTag[T]` types.